# AngularJS configuration module not being found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to the AngularJS framework, but basically what I am trying to do is inject a CSRF token into my app, but I want to change the url based on a config. Here is what I have so far:

```
var VERISION_API = 'v1';
var config_data = {
    'CFG': {
        'EP': 'https://mydomain.com/api/' + VERISION_API + '/web/'
    }
};
var configMod = angular.module("cfg",[]);
angular.forEach(config_data,function(key,value) {
  configMod.constant(value,key);
});

var myApp = angular.module("app", ["cfg", "ngResource", "ngRoute"]);

(function () {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    $injector.invoke(['cfg', '$http', '$rootScope', function (cfg, $http, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function (CFG) {
            $http.get(CFG.EP + "accounts/csrf").then(function (response) {
                myApp.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", response.csrf_token);
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            });
        });
    }]);
})();
```

I keep getting the following error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cfgProvider <- cfg

I know it has something to do with the way that I am running the $injector.invoke, but I have tried everything. Hopefully someone could help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Might be case sensitive, try `'CFG'` as a value to inject into `$injector`.

Comment: @DavinTryon That is not just the issue though... You need the module in the injector as well.

Comment: @PSL ah yeah, missed that.  Frankly, I've never seen it done like this.  I'd prefer an http interceptor, I think.

Comment: @DavinTryon oh yeah that is a good point.. I actually did not even see what is it doing. Plus `cfg` since it is a part of app's dependency list `CFG` will just be accessibly in the module `app`, and the token can just be adden via the interceptor or it can even be [added like this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers). But not sure is that is exactly what OP is doing in the real piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues, See inline:-

```
  var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'cfg']); //<-- Add module name here
   /*Injection is case sensitive it mustbe CFG*/
    $injector.invoke(['CFG', '$http', '$rootScope', function (cfg, $http, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () { //Do not set an argument here
            $http.get(cfg.EP + "accounts/csrf").then(function (response) {
                myApp.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", response.csrf_token);
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            });
        });
    }]);
```

1) You need to get the injector with the module that has the dependency, example:

```
 var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'cfg']);
```

2)  DI service/provider/etc.. names are case sensitive so:

```
  $injector.invoke(['CFG',...
```

3) Do not pass an argument in the anonymous function of `$rootScope.$apply` it will create a local variable within that scope. So just:

```
  $rootScope.$apply(function () {
```

injected dependency is available as variable (argument `cfg`) from the upper scope, so just access it as:

```
   $http.get(cfg.EP + "accounts/csrf");
```

Check the network console in the demo:

```js
var configMod = angular.module("cfg", []);
var config_data = {
  'CFG': {
    'EP': 'https://mydomain.com/api//web/'
  }
};
var configMod = angular.module("cfg", []);
angular.forEach(config_data, function(key, value) {
  configMod.constant(value, key);
});
var myApp = angular.module("app", ["cfg", "ngResource", "ngRoute"]);

(function() {
  var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'cfg']); //<-- Add module name here
  /*Injection is case sensitive it mustbe CFG*/
  $injector.invoke(['CFG', '$http', '$rootScope',
    function(cfg, $http, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() { //Do not set an argument here
        $http.get(cfg.EP + "accounts/csrf").then(function(response) {
          myApp.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", response.csrf_token);
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
      });
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

angular gets service from `providerCache` by exact the string key case sensitive, so `CFG` should be used